# Changing Function Access Mode in Derived Class

Tags: c++, inheritance, access-modifiers

Consider the following snippet:

```
struct Base
{
  virtual ~Base() {}

  virtual void Foo() const = 0; // Public
};

class Child : public Base
{
  virtual void Foo() const {} // Private
};

int main()
{
  Child child;

  child.Foo(); // Won't work. Foo is private in this context.

  static_cast<Base&> (child).Foo(); // Okay. Foo is public in this context.
}
```

Is this legal C++? "This" being changing the virtual function's access mode in the derived class.

Comment: @SauceMaster, That's not a very good indication of whether code is legal in C++.  There's loads and loads of C++ code that'll compile and run, but is still invoking undefined behaviour.  Change compilers, compiler flags, compiler version, and boom, it stops working.

Comment: Agreed with Glen. That's why I asked here.

Comment: Apart from the one error "Foo is private in this context", g++ accepts it.

Comment: Even if it is legal C++, remember that your maintenance programmers will hunt you down if you do this in production code.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, changing the access mode in derived classes is legal.

This is **similar** in form but **different** in intent to the [Non-Virtual Interface](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface) idiom. Some rationale is given [here](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm):

> The point is that virtual functions exist to allow customization; unless they also need to be invoked directly from within derived classes' code, there's no need to ever make them anything but private.

As to why you would actually make something `public` in base but `private` in derived without `private` or `protected` inheritance is beyond me.

Comment: Nice. I was using this approach for a formatting facet but wasn't sure if this was legal. Thank you!

Comment: This is quite contrary to the NVI: The base class' function is public+virtual, but in NVI it's private+virtual and the public function calling it is nonvirtual.

Comment: @litb, Ah, whups. Well, I fixed the text since I missed the base public virtual, derived private virtual.

Comment: It still doesn't address the actual question of the legality of changing access to members.

Comment: I thought that was apparent based on the articles I linked to.

Comment: @MSN: Could you expand on this please "As to why you would actually make something public in base but private in derived without private or protected inheritance is beyond me."

Answer (score 22):

This is legal C++, §11.6/1 says:

> Access is checked at the call point
>   using the type of the expression used
>   to denote the object for which the
>   member function is called (B* in the
>   example above). The access of the
>   member function in the class in which
>   it was defined (D in the example
>   above) is in general not known.

As you noted, `Child::Foo()` is thus still accessible via the base class, which is in most cases undesired:

```
 Child* c = new Child;
 Base* b = c;
 c->Foo(); // doesn't work, Child::Foo() is private
 b->Foo(); // works, calls Child::Foo()
```

Basically, the declaration you refer to in the expression dictates the access mode - but virtual functions undermine that as another function then the named one may actually be invoked.

Comment: So which implementation of `Foo` is executed in `b->Foo()`? `Child::Foo` or `Base::Foo`? If `Child::Foo` this breaks access control in the derived class.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: The comment in the same line says which ;)

Answer (score 5):

It is perfectly legal C++. You are simply defining a new method in Child class.

Now does it do what you want it to do, that's an other question.
I believe the access mode is not part of the method signature, which means that calling Base's Foo virtual method does eventually call Child's Foo method.

So here's the conclusion : **it is legal c++ and it works the way you'd expect.**

I am not taking into consideration the line `child.Foo();` which can't work because there is no doubt it is trying to access Child's private Foo() method.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to compile and call the right method.

Remember that access specifiers are there to help a disciplined programmer, not to prevent all attempts to circumvent it at all costs.

In this particular case, Child has no business making the overridden virtual function private: isn't it supposed to implement the public interface of Base, so the "is-a" relationship holds? (If you didn't use public inheritance, which means "Child is a Base", your trick wouldn't work.)

Comment: "Remember that access specifiers are there to help a disciplined programmer, not to prevent all attempts to circumvent it at all costs." is a great point