# using-declaration doesn't works correctly

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, polymorphism, using-declaration

In the following example, I'm trying to hide `using Employee::showEveryDept` from the last child class `Designer` by making it private in class `Elayer` -

```
#include <iostream>

class Employee {
private:
    char name[5] = "abcd";
    void allDept() { std::cout << "Woo"; }

public:
    void tellName() { std::cout << name << "\n"; }
    virtual void showEveryDept()
    {
        std::cout << "Employee can see every dept\n";
        allDept();
    }
};

class ELayer : public Employee {
private:
    using Employee::showEveryDept;

protected:
    ELayer() {}

public:
    using Employee::tellName;
};

class Designer : public ELayer {
private:
    char color = 'r';

public:
    void showOwnDept() { std::cout << "\nDesigner can see own dept\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    Employee* E = new Designer;
    E->showEveryDept(); // should not work

    Designer* D = dynamic_cast<Designer*>(E);
    D->showOwnDept();
}
```

But it is still compiling and the output is -

> ```
> Employee can see every dept
> Woo
> Designer can see own dept
> ```

But I've explicitly made it private, see - `private: using Employee::showEveryDept;`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ please tell a good linux based compiler which uses gui. I'm currently not so comfortable with using gdb directly and dirt poor to buy windows.

Comment: @hg_git If you're asking me for an IDE recommendation, I'd suggest Eclipse CDT.

Comment: @hg_git plain command line gdb then. I'm fine with Eclipse, even at my lame laptop.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ a debugger is no help in finding why code doesn't generate an expected compilation error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Names of class members have the following properties:

- The *name* - an unqualified identifier.
- The *declarative region* - which class the name was declared in.
- The *access* - rights of the name within that region.

This applies to the names themselves -- not to any variable or function that a name refers to. It is possible to have the same function or variable named by the same name but in a different declarative region.

When a class is inherited, the derived class's declarative region includes all names from the base class; but the access may be changed based on the type of inheritance: although it's only possible to declare a member as `public`, `protected`, or `private`,  after inheritance you can end up with a member having *no access*.

Here is a table of accessability of names and regions in your code:

[image: Name accessibility]

Note how `tellName` is public in all three classes, despite the fact that it was not redeclared in `Designer`. Accordingly, the `ELayer`'s `using Employee::tellName;` is redundant because `tellName` would have been `public` in `ELayer` anyway.

The effect of `ELayer`'s `using Employee::showEveryDept;` is that `showEveryDept`'s access *within `ELayer`* is `private`.

---

*Name Lookup* is the process of resolving which name-region combination is found by a call to a name. The context of this call includes:

- The *call site*, i.e. the scope in which the name was used
- Any explicitly-listed scope in the call (e.g. `Foo::name`)
- The expression denoting object whose member is being accessed (e.g. `(*E)`)

*Access control* also takes into account:

- The relationship between the calling context and the declarative region in which the name was found.

For example, looking up `showEveryDept` in the context of `ELayer` will find the combination `ELayer::showEveryDept` with access `private`.

But looking up the same name in the context of `Employee` will find the combination `Employee::showEveryDept` which has access `public`.

This behaviour is the same whether or not those two combinations refer to the same function.

Without reproducing the full list of rules about how the calling context translates to which declarative regions are searched, the usage:

```
`E->showEveryDept`
```

looks up the name in the region of the *static type* of `*E`, which is `Employee`.  It does not use the dynamic type, because name lookup is resolved at compile-time.  There are no run-time access errors -- access is a compile-time property.

The final step of the access check is to compare `public` and `Employee` with the call site, which is `main()`.  The rule is that `public` grants access to all call sites, so the access check passes.

---

*virtual*-ness does not depend on the properties of names, nor the scope in which the name is being looked up.  Unlike *access*, being virtual is a property of the function, not of any name-region combinations.

When *virtual dispatch* is active, calling a function will redirect the call to the final overrider of that function.

It's important to keep thinking of this in terms of function implementations - not of names for the functions.  Virtual dispatch and Access Control are two completely separate operations.

Virtual dispatch is active only when a virtual function is called by an *unqualified-id*, which means by naming the function without `Bla::` on the front.

So, in your code, `E->showEveryDept` does activate virtual dispatch.  The access check passes as described above, and then virtual dispatch invokes the final overrider, which happens to be the body defined in `Employee` in this example.

In your actual example, `virtual` is moot since the function is not overridden. But even if you had overridden `showEveryDept` as a private function in `ELayer` (instead of the `using` declaration), it would still call that function body.

Comment: you must be a teacher by profession, knew exactly what I was missing to understand this problem :D

Comment: @hg_git heh, thanks for the award... I'm not sure what you were missing but I tried to hit all the bases

Answer (score 14):

You are thinking about it the wrong way.

C++ has the concept of [Name Lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup), it's a well built concept that doesn't often come to our minds, but this happens everywhere a [name](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers#Names) is used. By doing:

```
int main()
{
    Employee* E = new Designer;
    E->showEveryDept(); // should not work

    Designer* D = dynamic_cast<Designer*>(E);
    D->showOwnDept();
}
```

The line, `E->showEveryDept()` does an unqualified name lookup for a member (member function in this case) belonging to the class of `E`. Since it's an [accessible name](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access), the program is legal.

---

We, also know `Designer` was derived from `ELayer`, where `showEveryDept()` is declared `private` as you did here:

```
class ELayer : public Employee {
private:
    using Employee::showEveryDept;

protected:
    ELayer() {}

public:
    using Employee::tellName;
};
```

But what you simply did was to explicitly [introduce](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration) the name `showEveryDept()` from `Employee` class into `Elayer`; introduced into a `private` access. Meaning, we cannot directly access that name (or call that function) associated with `ELayer` outside the class member/static functions.

```
ELayer* e = new Designer();
e->showEveryDept();    //Error, the name showEveryDept is private within ELayer
```

However, since `showEveryDept()` has a `public` access within the base class of `Elayer`, `Employer`; it can still be accessed using [qualified name lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/qualified_lookup)

```
ELayer* e = new Designer();
e->Employer::showEveryDept();    //Ok, qualified name lookup, showEveryDept is public
```

The names from `Elayer` which are accessible in `Designer` will be dictated by its [access specification](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access). As you can see, the name, `showEveryDept()` is private, so `Designer` cannot even use such name.

For your current class hierarchy and definitions, it means that, given:

```
Employee* E = new Designer();
ELayer*   L = new Designer();
Designer* D = new Designer();
```

-- For [unqualified lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup):

- This works

  ```
  E->showEveryDept();                // works!
  ```
- This fails:

  ```
  L->showEveryDept();                // fails; its private in Elayer
  ```
- This also fails:

  ```
  D->showEveryDept();                // fails; its inaccessible in Designer
  ```

-- For [qualified lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/qualified_lookup), in this case, requesting to call such function from its base class:

- This fails:

  ```
  D->Elayer::showEveryDept();        // fails! its private in Elayer
  ```
- This works:

  ```
  D->Employee::showEveryDept();      // works! its accessible in Employee
  ```
- This also works:

  ```
  L->Employee::showEveryDept();      // works! its accessible in Employee
  ```

---

Note that: introducing the name of any member function, `B::func`(for example) from a base class `B`, into a derived class `D`, does not override `B::func`, it simply makes  `B::func` visible to overload resolution within the context of the derived class. See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72010/c-overload-resolution) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411103/function-with-same-name-but-different-signature-in-derived-class)

Comment: My aim is to let it get called directly by `Employee` class objects, but fail if it is being called by anyone who derives from `ELayer`

Comment: This is a very good answer, and the only reason I accepted other because that was more clear to me. Still you answer did help me a lot :)

Answer (score 5):

The statement

```
E->showEveryDept();
```

accesses `showEveryDept` in the type known at compile time for `*E`. Which is `Employee`, where this member is accessible.

Comment: would you mind correcting me? `Employee* E = new Designer;` defines a pointer of type `Employee` but points to an object of type `Designer`, right?  So `E->showEveryDept()` is actually calling `showEveryDept()` method on `Designer` object, or no? Because then it is well hidden!

Comment: Yes, the virtual call resolves down to the most derived class. But the rules are as they are because in the general case that most derived class can't be known at compile time, even with global analysis. E.g. it can depend on user input.

Comment: Not sure if you maybe think `private` virtual member functions can't be called virtually. They can. Many people recommend making virtual member functions `private`, although, for some unexplained reason (I can't recall discussing this with Marshall) it's not the recommendation of the old FAQ, and therefore probably not of the ISO CPP FAQ either.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf - https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#private-virtuals 3rd para.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal: Thanks! Summary: the ISO CPP FAQ does recommend private virtuals, and explains why the old FAQ did not (risk of novice confusion).

Comment: It might be good to mention the difference between *static type* and *dynamic type* of `*E`, since that is apparently where OP's confusion lies

Answer (score 0):

In your `main()` function, be explicit about your type and call it like this -

```
int main()
{
    Employee* E = new Designer;
    E->showEveryDept(); // will work

    Designer* D = dynamic_cast<Designer*>(E);
    D->showOwnDept();
    D->showEveryDept();   // <-- Not legal now
}
```

It will produce the error -

> ```
> prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
> prog.cc:28:22: error: 'virtual void Employee::showEveryDept()' is inaccessible within this context
>      D->showEveryDept();
>                       ^
> prog.cc:8:26: note: declared here
>              virtual void showEveryDept(){std::cout<< "Employee can see every dept\n";
> ```

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong here?

You are not doing anything wrong.*

Is the expected result that is wrong:

The access specifier of the virtual function is checked on the type Employee and not on Designer as you might expect => [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2141461/2164989)

(*) Except the fact that changing the access rule to a virtual method over the hierarchies is bad design to my mind => [check this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) .